# Как в модульной таблице стилей react, указать переменную, если сам класс является переменой?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Как в **react** модульной таблице стилей, можно указать 2 переменные?

Одна как класс, а другая значение. 
Мой вариант дает мне ошибку.

```
import styles from "styles.module.scss";

let number = 1;

document.body.classList.add(`${styles.is_`${number}`}`);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот так можно сделать

```
import styles from "styles.module.scss";

let number = 1;

document.body.classList.add(styles[`is_${number}`]);
```

Пример для воспроизведения

```js
const styles = {
  is_1: 'id_1_style',
  is_2: 'id_2_style',
  is_3: 'id_3_style',
}

let number = 1;

console.log(styles[`is_${number}`])
```

Comment: Спасибо. Про массив я даже не догадывался

Comment: @Alexsander Это не массив, а строковое значение ключа в объекте. Когда мы знаем ключ, мы можем написать так `styles.is_4` или так `styles['is_4']`, а когда не значем, можем передать переменную `styles[myVariable]`